# How to add anchored models?

Tags: drake

When building a robot with environments, I would like to mark those objects in the env as anchored.
Using `Parser(plant).AddModelsXXX`, it seems there is no options to mark the added geometries as anchored.
I also use `WeldFrames` to fix those geometries. But that does not automatically mark geometries attached to the welded frame as anchored.

How can I mark geometries as anchored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I mark [Parser] geometries as anchored [... in SceneGraph]?

There is currently no easy way to accomplish that.  There is an open feature request [drake#8943](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8943) that describes the feature you're looking for.

At the moment, there is no evidence that this feature makes any substantial difference in performance, so the issue has been given a very low priority.

If you posted some benchmark code into that issue that illustrates why the performance matters in your case, that might help the Drake maintainers to prioritize the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate news is that there is no act by `MultibodyPlant` that will (currently) change a geometry's status from being "dynamic" to being "anchored".

I'm curious as to *why* you're trying to do this. What problem are you encountering such that you hope changing a geometry's classification will solve?

Comment: It will accelerate the distance computation, i.e., distances between anchored objects are not needed.

Comment: While it's technically true that filtered collisions still have a broadphase cost, do you have so many anchored geometries that you can discern that cost?

Presumably, you're already using the `max_distance` value to the extent that you can? The final remaining option is to enumerate all of the pairs of geometries that you care about and fire them off pair by pair -- this would limit the scope, but depending on the types and number of geometries may not be faster.